# Как в Yii2 запросить связанные данные?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как в Yii2 средствами activerecord запросить связанные данные. Связь между таблицами есть в БД, с помощью Gii связь перенесена в модель. Но при запросе вида $blocks = Block::find()->all(); в массиве нет связанных данных.

Модель

```
class Block extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
     {
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'block';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_presents', 'id_type'], 'required'],
        [['id_presents', 'id_type'], 'integer'],
        [['id_type'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TypeBlock::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_type' => 'id_type']],
        [['id_presents'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Presents::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_presents' => 'id_presents']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_block' => 'Id Block',
        'id_presents' => 'Презентация',
        'id_type' => 'Тип',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TypeBlock::className(), ['id_type' => 'id_type']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPresents()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Presents::className(), ['id_presents' => 'id_presents']);
}
```

}

Comment: `$blocks = Block::find()->with(['type', 'presents'])->all()` Так что выводит?

Comment: В массиве к каждому элементу добавился массив с типами

Comment: А как смотрите и что ожидается? Получаете данные с `->asArray()`?

Comment: Смотрел var_dump'ом. А с ->asArray() не понял Вас немного

Comment: `var_dump` покажет структуру объекта, а не данные. Вот так посмотрите `var_dump(Block::find()->with(['type', 'presents'])->asArray()->all());`

Comment: [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id_block"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id_presents"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id_type"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "Табы"
    }
  }
Получается примерно вот так. Думаю дальше уже сам что-нибудь натворю. Огромное спасибо за уделенное мне время и помощь

Comment: Из вас информацию буквально вытягивать приходится. Что ожидаете увидеть, какие результаты выдает SQL запрос из бд? Есть ли связанные данные, как выглядят связанные модели?

Comment: Оформлю ответ, раз получилось.

Comment: array(4) {
    ["id_block"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id_presents"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "Табы"
  }
Вообще ожидаю увидеть вот такое

Comment: Добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления в результаты запроса зависимостей используйте [with](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail).
С учетом ваших связей запрос на выборку будет выглядеть так:

`Block::find()->with(['type', 'presents'])->all()`

Для просмотра полученных данных с помощью var_dump добавьте `asArray()` перед `->all();`

Если используется GridView, поля можно выбирать через конфигурацию грида:

```
[
 'attribute' => 'type',
 'value' => 'type.name'
],
```