# Не работает LEFT JOIN yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

В контроллере пишу следующие

```
$results = Clients::find()
    ->select('*')
    ->leftJoin('orders', 'clients.id = orders.id')
    ->all();
```

Но данные возвращаются только из таблицы clients

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать

```
$results = Clients::find()
->select('*')
->joinWith('orders o', 'clients.id = o.id')
->all();
```

Comment: Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
app\models\Clients has no relation named "orders".

Comment: @t16bz вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622051/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-yii2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5?rq=1)  не то?

Comment: То. Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Оно и не будет работать. Вы получаете модели для таблицы clients. Они ничего не знают о таблице orders.
Либо не используйте эктив рэкрд либо используйте реляции: hasOne, hasMany.